# API which detects incoming call in android

Tags: android, android-intent

which api detects first incoming call in android phone can anyone tell me or the first action comes into play by which api and where it happens when incoming call comes

Comment: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Answer (score 0):

Learn about Broadcast and BroadcastReceiver (Abstract Class) to get broadcasts about incoming calls, sms, mms, wifi etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html